# Rendering HTML in a WebView with custom CSS

Tags: android, html, css, webview

My app is using JSoup to download the HTML of a message board page (let's say in this case it is a page containing the posts of a given thread). I'd like to take this HTML, strip out unwanted items, and apply custom CSS to style it to be 'mobile' in a WebView.

Should I inject the styles into the HTML as I process it (since I will be processing it anyway) or is there a good way to add a CSS file to my app's assets and simply refer to it. I figure the latter would be ideal, but unsure how to go about it.

I see hints in WebView's [loadDataWithBaseURL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) that you can refer to local assets, but not sure how to utilize it.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You could use [WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
htmlData = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />" + htmlData;
// lets assume we have /assets/style.css file
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

And only after that WebView will be able to find and use css-files from the assets directory.

ps And, yes, if you load your html-file form the assets folder, you don't need to specify a base url.

Comment: Thanks! That was just what I needed. (Incidentally, you can use single quotes for the attributes in the inline HTML instead of double-quotes; that way you won't need to backslash them. Always looks a bit tidier to me...)

Comment: Nice. I would put the PS as the direct answer: If you load your html file with WebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/fname.html"); you can simply use relative urls within it.

Comment: How can we use the loadDataWithBaseURL() if the stylesheet is in file storage? can we use 'data/data/etc/"?

Comment: @Yasir, it works even if your `style.css` file is saved away in the the android file storage. You just need to make sure that `baseUrl` is perfect and matches the `css` files relative path.

Comment: Thank you @AndresD.

Comment: If your files are the raw folder and not in assets ([which](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43663133/3918479) gives you Android Localization), the base URL would be "file:///android_res/raw/"

Comment: How to this by avoiding the reload of the already loaded html? I have an HTML loaded from the server and I also try to load another local CSS file, but it seems the html is gone afterward.

Comment: Good job. But what if I want to load css from another module location? may it is impossible so can i pass the style.css class it self to module?

Comment: I think this doesn't work with dynamic JS generated webpages, at least it doesn't for me.

Comment: What if you want to load css and js from an external server?

Answer (score 37):

I assume that your style-sheet "style.css" is already located in the assets-folder

1. load the web-page with jsoup:

   ```
   doc = Jsoup.connect("http://....").get();
   ```
2. remove links to external style-sheets:

   ```
   // remove links to external style-sheets
   doc.head().getElementsByTag("link").remove();
   ```
3. set link to local style-sheet:

   ```
   // set link to local stylesheet
   // <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
   doc.head().appendElement("link").attr("rel", "stylesheet").attr("type", "text/css").attr("href", "style.css");
   ```
4. make string from jsoup-doc/web-page:

   ```
   String htmldata = doc.outerHtml();
   ```
5. display web-page in webview:

   ```
   WebView webview = new WebView(this);
   setContentView(webview);
   webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/.", htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
   ```

Comment: nice practical solution, do not forget to not to use that in UI (Main) thread.

Comment: I want to access style.css from another module. If this is impossible, is there another way to load style as string then pass to  library module class?

Answer (score 22):

here is the solution

Put your html and css in your /assets/ folder, then load the html file like so:

```
    WebView wv = new WebView(this);

    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourHtml.html");
```

then in your html you can reference your css in the usual way

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
```

Answer (score 9):

It's as simple as is:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/some.html");
```

And your some.html needs to contain something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have your CSS in the internal file storage you can use

```
//Get a reference to your webview
WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webby);

// Prepare some html, it is formated with css loaded from the file style.css
String webContent = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\"></head>"
                      + "<body><div class=\"running\">I am a text rendered with INDIGO</div></body></html>";

//get and format the path pointing to the internal storage
String internalFilePath = "file://" + getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/";

//load the html with the baseURL, all files relative to the baseURL will be found 
web.loadDataWithBaseURL(internalFilePath, webContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: The example of `webContent` here made me to solve my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped @JorgeAmVF!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to have all the content rendered in-page, in a given div? You could then reset the css based on the id, and work on from there.

Say you give your div id="ocon"

In your css, have a definition like:

```
#ocon *{background:none;padding:0;etc,etc,}
```

and you can set values to clear all css from applying to the content.
After that, you can just use

```
#ocon ul{}
```

or whatever, further down the stylesheet, to apply new styles to the content.

Answer (score 0):

**You can Use Online Css link To set Style over existing content.**

For That you have to load data in webview and enable JavaScript Support.

**See Below Code:**

```
   WebSettings webSettings=web_desc.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    webSettings.setTextZoom(55);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<HTML><HEAD><LINK href=\" http://yourStyleshitDomain.com/css/mbl-view-content.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/></HEAD><body>");
    sb.append(currentHomeContent.getDescription());
    sb.append("</body></HTML>");
    currentWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Here  Use StringBuilder to append String for Style.

```
sb.append("<HTML><HEAD><LINK href=\" http://yourStyleshitDomain.com/css/mbl-view-content.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/></HEAD><body>");
sb.append(currentHomeContent.getDescription());
```