# Android change select dialog text color

Tags: android

I am using  WebView in my Android app. When I click on a select, a window with the select options is displayed, but the options color and background is both white, so they cannot be read, how can I change this style? If I open the same website on the regular Android browser then the options are rendered properly, So I'm guessing this is a problem with my styling, but
I cannot pinpoint which style option is the one responsible.

Note that this is not a listview, but a regular web browser select popup dialog.

Comment: I guess, you need to fix css on the site, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950729/rendering-html-in-a-webview-with-custom-css, i mean only that part with selected font color

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work, also if I load the website on the regular browser on my phone it looks good.

Comment: so maybe then you need to do something with the theme of application ?

Comment: Probably, that's what I was trying to ask, how can I change the style of that particular control

Comment: Have you seen this link http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/ ?

Comment: Also you will find a little bit here http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/webview/android-webview-example/

Comment: I'm sorry, friend. I'm totally suck with this question...

Comment: no problem, you tried :)

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew Dashin(https://stackoverflow.com/a/8369422/720097):

You could use WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL

```
htmlData = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />" + htmlData;
// lets assume we have /assets/style.css file
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

And only after that WebView will be able to find and use css-files from the assets directory.

ps And, yes, if you load your html-file form the assets folder, you don't need to specify a base url.