# Is it possible to view local website files on Android Ice Cream Sandwich?

Tags: android, local

I have a simple html website I am trying to view as a local version on a tablet with ICS. The html works, but the css and js files do not seem to work. All I am seeing is the html. Is there something I need to do in order to view the website in its full form?

I am not using any special code specifically for mobile. There is only a folder, an index.html file, and folders for js and css.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <title>Kiosk Site</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
    <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: post a bit of your code, are you using WebView?

Answer (score 1):

Some of your code would be appreciated.

I persume you're using a WebView:

1. Regarding the JS - you need to call [setJavascriptEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled%28boolean%29).
2. Reagrding the CSS - it's hard to tell with none of your code. But I would suggest you look at this: [Rendering HTML in a WebView with custom CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950729/rendering-html-in-a-webview-with-custom-css).