# How to add local css file to a page in WebView?

Tags: android, html, css, webview

So, I have a WebView showing page from url:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.showContentWebView);
String url = "http://edition.cnn.com/2014/02/05/sport/shaun-white-sochi-slopestyle/index.html";
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

And I also have a file "style.css" in my assets folder. How can I display the page in WebView with style.css connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is possible only if you somehow process the HMTL content, adding a link to your css file. In this case, please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950729/rendering-html-in-a-webview-with-custom-css).