# Android Studio - How to show only body in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-studio, header

I want to hide header and footer and only show the body content in the webview. My website is made with WordPress.

Footer is not the main thing. The main thing is to hide header. So, if you do not have and idea to hide footer, please provide the code for header only.

I searched on the internet but nothing seemed to work for me.

Thanks

Comment: You need to inject custom CSS, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950729/rendering-html-in-a-webview-with-custom-css

Comment: @GregEnnis - Thanks for the reply. But, the link you refer to is not the local HTML files. How do I do it if I am loading the webview content from my website which is live. 

Sorry, I am newbie so don't know much. So, I might be talking stupid :p 

But, can you explain?

Comment: OK, if it is your website, then just include the responsive CSS in your site so that when the width < 800px (or whatever), do not display the header and footer.