# How can I change the font of a WebView?^

Tags: android

I want to use a Custom Font in a WebView in android Studio

```
public void loadHTLMContentText(String text, WebView view) {

    String body;
    String head = "<head><style><style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: 'Standard';src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/Standard.ttf')}body {font-family: Standard;text-align: justify;}</style></head>";
    if (text != null) {
        body = text;
    } else return;
    String htmlData = "<html>" + head + "<body>" + body + "</body></html>";


    view.loadData(htmlData, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
    view.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

}
```

I use this code to generate the HTLM file with the content. The custom font ist under the Path
C:\Users\julia\AndroidStudioProjects\AktienApp\app\src\main\assets\fonts.

Then I load the content in the webview with this

```
WebView text_1_a = (WebView) one.findViewById(R.id.text_slide_type_a_1);
        preparer.loadHTLMContentText(getString(R.string.Historie1), text_1_a);
```

But it doesn't change the font. Anybody got my failure?

Comment: it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8369422/2657100

Comment: doesn't helped :/

Answer (score 1):

Here I make one simple demo program for changing font in WebView.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webview1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webview1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        webview1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo.html");
    }
}
```

And I create assets folder and put one HTML file inside that folder.

demo.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face { font-family: 'Persian'; src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/Myfont.ttf'); }
        @font-face { font-family: 'Persian2'; src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/newfont.ttf'); }
        body {font-family: 'Persian';}
        h1 {font-family: 'Persian2';}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Welcome to CustomFont Demo
</h1>
    Testing text
</body>
</html>
```

And inside assets folder, I create one more folder for font.
folder name is fonts.

So I use font uri like : file:///android_asset/fonts/Myfont.ttf