# append some style to android WebView

Tags: android, webview

I am using WebView in my application that load a website. I want to add some style to WebView.

How can i append my custom style to WebView after load website.

**Code** :

```
    wvShop.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wvShop.loadUrl("http://SOME_URL");
    wvShop.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    wvShop.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950729/rendering-html-in-a-webview-with-custom-css

Comment: @AmitabhSarkar .  Thanks for suggest but i need load website first and then add some custom style