# Style property not working in webview

Tags: android, html, css, webview, styles

I am loading html pages from assets and showing in application. HTML pages are showing but when I tried to change background color of button on "onclick" then background color is not getting change.

If i test pages with browser then it's working but when I load html pages in android using webview then it's not working.

onclick function getting called but somehow style property not getting applied. 
I tried following three ways.

```
1. $('#btnAC').css({'background-image', 'linear-gradient(180deg, black, red) !important'});  

2. document.getElementById("btnAC").style = "background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, black, red) !important;";  

3. $('#btnAC').css('background-image', 'linear-gradient(180deg, black, red) !important');
```

Java code :

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http:///android_asset/Web/index.html");
```

Comment: make sure you have set java script  interface enable.
`webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`
`webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);`

Comment: yes already added

Comment: **This may be help you** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950729/rendering-html-in-a-webview-with-custom-css

Comment: I had the same problem. What I did is to apply style two times instead of only once. However with a recent webview update this is not working anymore. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL

- htmlData = "" + htmlData;
  // lets assume we have /assets/style.css file
  webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);*